# WiFi direct returns P2P_UNSUPPORTED

Tags: android, p2p, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have a real android device (Android 4.1.1). Which supports applications like Xender, ShareIt, Zapya etc which uses WiFi Direct to transfer files.

But when I run my application, it says P2P_UNSUPPORTED.

**My manifest permissions are....**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**My MainActivity.java is like this..**

```
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    Receiver receiver=new Receiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver,intentFilter);

    WifiP2pManager manager=(WifiP2pManager)getSystemService(WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    channel=manager.initialize(this, Looper.getMainLooper(),null);

    manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // Code for when the discovery initiation is successful goes here.
            // No services have actually been discovered yet, so this method
            // can often be left blank.  Code for peer discovery goes in the
            // onReceive method, detailed below.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
            // Code for when the discovery initiation fails goes here.
            // Alert the user that something went wrong.
            switch (reasonCode){
                case WifiP2pManager.BUSY:Log.e("code","BUSY");break;
                case WifiP2pManager.ERROR:Log.e("code","ERROR");break;
                case WifiP2pManager.P2P_UNSUPPORTED:Log.e("code","P2P_UNSUPPORTED");break;

            }
        }
    });
```

**In the Log,, I get.**

```
code﹕ P2P_UNSUPPORTED
```

**And my BraodcastReceiver is like this..**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Log.e("intent",intent.getAction());

    int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
    Log.e("raw state", ""+state);
    if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
        Log.e("state", "ON");
    } else if(state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_DISABLED) {
        Log.e("state", "DISABLED "+ state);
    }
}
```

**And there i get the log as,,**

```
raw state﹕ -1
```

**NOTE : the variable *state* neither equals WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED nor WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_DISABLED**

Comment: Try running Android's Wi-Fi Direct demo and see if P2P works: https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo
Here are some other Android Wi-Fi Direct resources as well: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wi-fi-direct/uWpuOzHY6y0

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the applications that you have listed are able to use alternative transports other than Wi-Fi Direct. The `P2P_UNSUPPORTED` error implies that your device does not have the Wi-Fi Direct feature.  You can try confirming this by executing the following: `getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI_DIRECT)`.  Alternatively, if your device has Wi-Fi Direct, you can access a Wi-Fi Direct settings activity from the Wi-Fi settings of your device.